# Error in loading hibImport in hipi

Tags: hipi

I have installed hadoop 2.7.1 and gardle 3.1 when tried to export my images from local file directory (.jpg) to hdfs (.hib) im getting this exception..pls help

below is the command :

```
hduser@nandhinilk-Inspiron-3558:/home/nandhinilk/hipi/tools$ ./hibImport.sh /home/nandhinilk/Desktop/sample -f sample.hib

Input FS: local FS
Output HIB: sample.hib
Overwrite HIB if it exists: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hipi.imagebundle.HipiImageBundle.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)V
    at org.hipi.tools.HibImport.main(HibImport.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute command without including -f in hibImport. Because by using -f it will search in hadoop file system not in your local directory.

```
./hibImport.sh /home/nandhinilk/Desktop/sample sample.hib
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply..but im receiving the same error

Comment: try to execute command without including -f in hibImport. Because by using -f it will search in hadoop file system not in your home directory.

Comment: $ ./hibImport.sh /home/nandhinilk/Desktop/sample sample.hib

Comment: I have changed the solution.. @AmmuNandy